# Jquery access div in table cell

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to access the first div with a class from hovering on a table row;

Here is my html:

```
<table id='search_job_results_table'>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><div style='position:relative'><div class='search_job_tooltip'>blah blah</div></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried with the following:

```
$(function () {
    $('table#search_jobs_result_table tbody tr').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).children().next('div.search_job_tooltip').css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```

The hovering works part works, as I can wak an alert in there and it triggers, but not setting the css of that div. I always get stuck on this for some reason, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `find()` method and instead of `.css('display', 'block');` you can use `show()` method.

```
$(function () {
    $('#search_jobs_result_table tr').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).find('.search_job_tooltip:first').show()
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help! - Sorry Ankit, your answer was correct but Raminson provided the show() as well... I wish I could select 2 answers or at least give a mention lol

Answer (score 1):

You can't use .next() because div is the children so use this one

```
$(function () {
    $('table#search_jobs_result_table tbody tr').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).find('div.search_job_tooltip').first().css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```